# Скрыть кнопку при условии

Tags: javascript, php

Есть сайт с авторизацией, на странице в самом начале стоит проверка, авторизован ли юзер:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once('db.php'); 
    if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
        $sesion_id=$_SESSION['userid'];
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `user` where id=$sesion_id");
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); 

        $result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `user_prefs` where id=$sesion_id");
        $user_prefs_row = $result2->fetch_assoc();

        $validsql=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `wallets` WHERE id='".$sesion_id."'");
        $valid_row = $validsql->fetch_assoc();
    }
    else{
        header("Location: http://www.site.com");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Можно ли как-то с помощью этого условия, как-то скрыть определенную кнопку на странице и наоборот отобразить другую? Т.е если юзер авторизован, отобразить кнопку logout, и если не авторизован, то отобразить login?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
echo '<form action="logout.php" name="log_clear" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="log_out">Выйти</button>
    </form>';
} else {
echo '<form action="login.php" name="log_in" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="log_in">Войти</button>
    </form>';
}
```

Файл `logout.php`:

```
session_start();
if ($_POST['log_out']) {
    unset($_SESSION['userid']);
    header("Location: http://www.site.com");
}
```

Файл `login.php` - то, что Вы привели или отдельно на страницу с установлением и проверкой `userid` в сессию.